# CSS displays differently on IE and Firefox

Tags: css

My site acro.batcave.net shows up differently on IE (Windows 7, IE 11.x) and FF (Windows 7, FF 37.x). Chrome has the same behavior as FF. The CSS is located at acro.batcave.net/css/index.css. Initially I thought I might have used non-standard CSS (the intent is to use CSS3). But I did not find any using the CSS validator at W3C. What am I doing wrong and how do I make FF (and Chrome) to display this similar to IE?

Comment: Test in Chrome or Chromium too.

Comment: Forget on validators, both HTML and CSS. Can you please post a screenshot of IE? CSS has just a few lines, maybe I can help you from screens.

Comment: @Michas, I have tested with Chrome also. Thanks for your non-answer.

Comment: @panther, thanks very much for your offer to help. Let me try Guffa's suggestion and if things do not work out, I will post the screenshots with the change. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how that's happening but when your site loads in Chrome the CSS returned is all gibberish. That's why its not getting applied.

Check out the screenshot below:

http://screencast.com/t/tCYGkUnAxO

Comment: thanks very much for your reply, The actual browser screen displays the character (of the HTML) correctly. The incorrect display of the CSS might be due to answers from Guffa. I will try and post his solution here.

Answer (score 2):

You have saved the HTML code as UTF-16 with a byte order mark, and I suspect that you have saved the CSS code the same way. Firefox and Chrome fail to decode the CSS file to text because of the encoding.

Most browsers doesn't support UTF-16 for data files unless you specify it in the link tag or the header. Instead save the files (the HTML too) as UTF-8, without a byte order mark.

Comment: I checked (sorry for the delay) but the CSS file was not encoded in UTF-16. So I believe that is not the problem.